# When i switching view and after 15 to 20 minutes The error is"error = 24 (Too many open files)"

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I am making application and i am using HD graphics. my application is good for 10 minutes but not for long time. after some time.... The error is occured:

```
error = 24 (Too many open files)
```

How to remove this error i am stuck, i am using camera and images buttons etc but there is no leaks just the above error occure after some time.please help.

Comment: Seems impossible to solve your problem without seeing the way you are actually loading the graphics.

Comment: Hi, i have handle this..memory was leak i have resolved..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove this error i am stuck, i
>   am using camera and images buttons etc
>   but there is no leaks just the above
>   error occure after some time.please
>   help.

Clearly, your claim that there are no leaks is highly suspect.

Namely, it looks like you are leaking file descriptors somehow.   Without more code in the question, impossible to say exactly how.

Show any code that opens files;  that'll be a good start.

Comment: Hi, i have handle this..memory was leak i have resolved..Thanks @bbum.